# Cannot find declaration to go after dependencies and build gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem after import library.

> Cannot find declaration to go

I have try to fix wit re-build, clean or restart android studio. So how to fix it?

my configure :

```
android studio 1.5 beta
gradle 1.3.1

compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxxx.xx'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```